# Pandas Method Chaining - Calculation Based on Criteria of Multiple Columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, method-chaining

I have started to try to implement method chaining to improve the readability of my code in Pandas. However, I am having difficulties coming up with a solution to assign a new calculated column based on criteria of values in three other columns.

What I am trying to do is to calculate transit days for different countries, carriers and carrier services based on shipping date vs delivery attempt date. There are differences between the markets, carriers and services (criteria) in the weekdays of shipping dates and delivery days (calculation).

Without method chaining I would use the below to count the transit days:

- df.loc[(criteria1), 'transit_days'] = np.busday_count(shipped_date, attempt_date, weekmask='1111100')
- df.loc[(criteria2), 'transit_days'] = np.busday_count(shipped_date, attempt_date, weekmask='1111110')
- df.loc[(criteria3), 'transit_days'] = np.busday_count(shipped_date, attempt_date, weekmask='1111111')

With method chaining the only solution I come up with is the '.apply' method and create a custom function with if/else statements which is not ideal and quite slow when calculating millions of rows. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**, adding the code, progress so far:

```
df = (pd
      .read_csv(filepath_or_buffer='data.csv')
      
      # Re-formating the column names to lowercase and replacing spaces with underscores
      .rename(columns=clean_column_names)
      
      # Filtering results to include only express orders
      .query('service_level == "Express"')
      
      # Dropping rows without delivery attempt
      .dropna(subset=['initial_delivery_attempt_date', 'available_for_pickup_time', 'final_delivery_date'], how='all')
      
      # Assigning new columns
      # 1. first_attempt = defining the first attempted delivery date
      # 2. transit_days = specific transit days for market 
      .assign(first_attempt = lambda x: x[['initial_delivery_attempt_date', 'available_for_pickup_time', 'final_delivery_date']].min(axis=1).astype('datetime64[D]'),
             transit_days = [STUCK HERE])
    )
df
```

**EDIT2**, I think I found the way to do it the same way with the loc operator by defining a function taking a dataframe through lambda:

First created the function:

```
def calculate_transit_days(df):
    df = df.copy()

    mask1 = (df['carrier'] == 'Carrier_1')
    mask2 = (df['carrier'] == 'Carrier_2')
    
    df.loc[mask1, 'new_column'] = np.busday_count(df.loc[mask1, 'shipped_time'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'), df.loc[mask1, 'first_attempt'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'), weekmask='1111111')
    df.loc[mask2, 'new_column'] = np.busday_count(df.loc[mask2, 'shipped_time'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'), df.loc[mask2, 'first_attempt'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'), weekmask='1111110')
    
    return df['new_column']
```

Then assigned the function in lambda:

```
df = (pd
      .read_csv(filepath_or_buffer='data.csv')
      
      # Re-formating the column names to lowercase and replacing spaces with underscores
      .rename(columns=clean_column_names)

      # Filtering results to include only express orders
      .query('customer_level_of_service == "Express"')
      
      # Dropping rows without delivery attempt
      .dropna(subset=['initial_delivery_attempt_date', 'available_for_pickup_time', 'delivery_date'], how='all')
      
      # Finding the first attempt date
      .assign(first_attempt = lambda x: x[['initial_delivery_attempt_date', 'available_for_pickup_time', 'delivery_date']].min(axis=1),
              transit_days = lambda x: calculate_transit_days(x))
      
     )
```

**EDIT3:**

Also, rather than defining each scenario (there were many) with .loc & mask, I noticed that np.select is useful here. First defining all the np.select(conditions) to a list that applies to weekmask ('1111110') and '(1111111'), and then with np.select(choicelist) running the correct busday_count functions, and entering weekmask ('1111100') as default.

In the below example I have listed two simplified condition criteria and two np.busday_count logics, so the length of the both list is 2. Then the default weekmask is Mon - Fri ('1111100').

```
def calculate_transit_days(df):
    df = df.copy()

    # Defining conditions into a list
    conditions = [
        # Conditions 1
            ((df['carrier'] == 'Carrier_1') | (df['shipped_time'].dt.weekday == 6)) |
            ((df['carrier'] == 'Carrier_2') | (df['shipped_time'].dt.weekday == 6)),
        
        # Conditions 2
            ((df['carrier'] == 'Carrier_3'))
    ]

     # Defining calculation for conditions
    choices = [
        # Choice for condition 1
        (np.busday_count(df['shipped_time'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'), df['first_attempt'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'), weekmask='1111111')),
        
        # Choice for condition 2
        (np.busday_count(df['shipped_time'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'), df['first_attempt'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'), weekmask='1111110'))
    ]
    
    
    
    df['new_column'] = np.select(
                                condlist = conditions, 
                                choicelist = choices,
                                default = np.busday_count(df['shipped_time'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'), df['first_attempt'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'), weekmask='1111100')
         )
    
    return df['new_column']
```

Comment: Why would method chaining help?  You are setting different rows on the same series at each step.  In chaining the next step modifies the frame produced by the previous.

Comment: I am practising to make my code more readable, therefore the chaining. I am used to creating temporary variables throughout the data wrangling process, but quite often the process from beginning to the end becomes quite a mess and hard to read.

Comment: That initial `dataframe` sequence works as a chain because each dataframe method returns a NEW dataframe.  `busday_count` is a numpy function that returns an array (or maybe a pandas Series)  `df.loc[(criteria1), 'transit_days']=...` assigns that to an existing (or new) Series of an existing dataframe.  It's not obvious that using `assign` to return a new frame, as opposed to the in-place assignment is any clearer.  I suspect it's less efficient (though my efficiency intuitions are better developed for `numpy` than `pandas`.)

Answer (score 0):

The ideas that come to mind are not cleaner than having 3 pretty clear instructions as you have.

For instance, you *could* calculate the 3 ways and multiply each of them by the condition.

Something in the lines of

```
df['transit_days'] = (
    criteria1 * np.busday_count(shipped_date, attempt_date, weekmask='1111100') + 
    criteria2 * np.busday_count(shipped_date, attempt_date, weekmask='1111110') +
    criteria3 * np.busday_count(shipped_date, attempt_date, weekmask='1111111')
)
```